# Underexposed image with Canon 5D III and flash

Tags: flash, exposure, hotshoe-flash, canon-5d-mark-iii, sync-speed

Just started using my Mark III with flash (Neewer TT560 Speedlite). And I'm getting strange results. At first I thought it was a battery issue and another set of batteries seemed to have fixed the problem, but now I'm getting this issue constantly.

This particular image was taken with following settings: f/2, 1/500s, ISO 500.

Any advise?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see the curtain of your camera: nice, no?

If you want to avoid that with mark III , use a shutter speed lower than 1/200s

You could use high flash speed sync, but I am quite sure that your flash can't use that, 
so with this flash, your only solution will be under 1/200s or use a ND filter to have less light entering your lens

Check this tutorial on high speed sync - This man is a master of flash photography : http://neilvn.com/tangents/high-speed-flash-sync/

This video is also quite interesting : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j5AHzAGaFk

Christian, France

Answer (score 2):

The black bar you are seeing is the curtain from your shutter. Your shutter speed (1/500) is faster than your camera's flash sync speed (1/200). To get rid of the black bars, you either need to enable "high speed sync" on your flash (if it has the feature), or choose a shutter speed of 1/200 or slower.